# Why dictionary keys get added to a list using extend()?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Why do keys get added instead of values when I try to add dictionary elements to a list?

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
lst.extend({"umang" : 10})
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4,'umang']
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `dict`'s `iter` method iterates over the keys, this is why `list({'a':1, 'b': 2})` returns `['a', 'b']`.

If you want `[1, 2, 3, 4, 10]` you have to explicitly use the dict values:

```
lst.extend({"umang" : 10}.values())
```